# Moving 2 forms at the same time

Tags: c#, winforms, winapi

I'm stuck a little bit here. I'm trying to move 2 forms at the same time without using OnMove, LocationChanged, Docking etc.

The only way to interact with their locations is to override WndProc. Something which might be helpful is that form A is owner of form B. So whenever A is moved I want to move B as well. Not to the same location but the same distance.

```
    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        if (m.Msg == 0x0084)
        {
              Form[] temp = this.OwnedForms;

              if(temp.Length > 0) 
              {
                    /* moving temp[0] to the same ratio as this form */
              }

              m.Result = (IntPtr)2;
              return;
        }
        base.WndProc(ref m);
    }
```

Both A and B have the same WndProc since they are 2 objects from the same class.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem:

```
protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
{
    Form temp = this.Owner;

    if (m.Msg == 0x0084)
    {
          m.Result = (IntPtr)2;
          return;
    }

    if (m.Msg == 0x0216 && temp != null)
    {
         if (!movedonce)
         {
              oldlocationx = this.Location.X;
              oldlocationy = this.Location.Y;
              movedonce = true;
         }

         temp.Location = new Point(temp.Location.X + this.Location.X - oldlocationx, temp.Location.Y + this.Location.Y - oldlocationy);
         oldlocationx = this.Location.X;
         oldlocationy = this.Location.Y;
    }

    base.WndProc(ref m);
}
```

Comment: what are movedonce and this?

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't make any sense to avoid using the LocationChanged event:

```
    private Point lastPos;

    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e) {
        base.OnLoad(e);
        lastPos = this.Location;
    }

    protected override void OnLocationChanged(EventArgs e) {
        base.OnLocationChanged(e);
        foreach (var frm in this.OwnedForms) {
            frm.Location = new Point(frm.Location.X + this.Left - lastPos.X,
                frm.Location.Y + this.Top - lastPos.Y);
        }
        lastPos = this.Location;
    }

    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m) {
        // Move borderless window with click-and-drag on client window
        if (m.Msg == 0x84) m.Result = (IntPtr)2;
        else base.WndProc(ref m);
    }
```

Comment: If locationchanged would work in my case I would use it. But since I'm using an alpha blended layeredwindow which just contains an image I have to finde a workaround.

Comment: I don't get the relevance.  Whether the user moves it with the caption bar or whether it gets moved some other way because it is a borderless window, the LocationChanged event still fires.  Triggered by same Window message you're trying to trap in WndProc().  WM_NCHITTEST doesn't have much to do with it, that's just for moving a borderless window.