# create custom datagridview popup control with close(X) button

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010

I want to create a control in my windows form application. This control contains some data as datagridview control. But my requirement is to show this control as popup control. Below is the screen shot of this.

[image]

Please help me to overcome this problem. Any help appreciated.

**NOTE:- I want my form same as above screen shot means i want only my datagridview to be visible and i don't want form header and its border.**

Comment: Where exactly is the problem? You can show your form with `form.Show()` and then set its position.

Comment: @Jens Kloster i want popup same as above screen shot. if i am adding this datagridview to windows form, it will show me form's title bar and form's border, so i want my popup exactly same as screen shot.

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own PopupForm with following code.

To remove the borders use [FormBorderStyle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.windows.forms.form.formborderstyle%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
this.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None;
```

Then place your DataGridView and your Button like that:
[image: Example Popup]

Use the DataGridView's Dock-Property to fill the form:

```
yourDataGridViewControl.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
```

Place your button in the right upper corner and create an [EventHandler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.eventhandler%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to catch the [Click-Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.windows.forms.control.click%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
button_close.Click += button_close_Click;
private void button_close_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Close();
}
```

**In your Mainform:**
Create following two fields:

```
PopupForm popup; //PopupForm is the name of your Form
Point lastPos; //Needed to move popup with mainform
```

Use following code to show your popup at the button's location:

```
void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(popup != null)
        popup.Close(); //Closes the last open popup

    popup = new PopupForm();
    Point location = button.PointToScreen(Point.Empty); //Catches the position of the button
    location.X -= (popup.Width - button.Width); //Set the popups X-Coordinate left of the button
    location.Y += button.Height; //Sets the location beneath the button
    popup.Show();
    popup.TopMost = true; //Is always on top of all windows
    popup.Location = location; //Sets the location

    if (popup.Location.X < 0) //To avoid that the popup 
        popup.Location = new Point(0, location.Y); //is out of sight
}
```

Create an EventHandler to catch the MainForm's Move-Event and use following method to move your popup with your MainForm ([Credit goes to Hans Passant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8185602/moving-2-forms-at-the-same-time)):

```
private void Form1_LocationChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        popup.Location = new Point(popup.Location.X + this.Left - lastPos.X,
            popup.Location.Y + this.Top - lastPos.Y);
        if (popup.Location.X < 0)
            popup.Location = new Point(0, popup.Location.Y);
    }
    catch (NullReferenceException)
    {
    }
    lastPos = this.Location;
}
```

Here you can get the Demoproject: [LINK](http://www.abouchleih.com/wp-content/uploads/CreateCustomDataGridViewCell_StackOverflow_19724409.zip)